# get all color variants from one base color

Tags: flutter, dart, colors

In my app the user picks one color and we need to show every color variant of the picked color like the below image.

I have no idea how to make this.

[image]

This is the simple stateful widget for this colorvariant project

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ColorVariant extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color baseColor;
  const ColorVariant({Key? key, required this.baseColor}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ColorVariant> createState() => _ColorVariantState();
}

class _ColorVariantState extends State<ColorVariant> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Color Variant'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: see https://pub.dev/packages/palette or https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_palette or https://pub.dev/packages/color_models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`flutter_color_models`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_color_models). With it, you can create a palette of gradient colors by just augmenting the number of colors.

Take a look on the following example. It creates 5 colors from `pink` to `white`:

```
final paletteRange = <ColorModel>[
  RgbColor.fromColor(Colors.pink),
  const RgbColor(255, 255, 255),
];
final palette = paletteRange.augment(5);
```

Here's a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of this approach that plays with HUE and Chroma values to generate color variants from `pink`:

[image: Screenshot]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_color_models/flutter_color_models.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final paletteRange = <ColorModel>[
            RgbColor.fromColor(Colors.pink),
            const RgbColor(255, 255, 255),
          ];
          final palette = paletteRange.augment(5);

          return Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: const RgbColor(0, 0, 0)
                      .withChroma(palette[index].chroma)
                      .toColor(),
                  height: 64,
                  width: 64,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: palette[index].toColor(),
                  height: 64,
                  width: 64,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: palette[index].rotateHue(-10).toColor(),
                  height: 64,
                  width: 64,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: palette[index].rotateHue(-20).toColor(),
                  height: 64,
                  width: 64,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: palette[index].rotateHue(-30).toColor(),
                  height: 64,
                  width: 64,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
        itemCount: 5,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass your baseColor to createMaterialColor()

```
MaterialColor createMaterialColor(Color color) {
  final strengths = <double>[.05];
  final swatch = <int, Color>{};
  final int r = color.red, g = color.green, b = color.blue;

  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    strengths.add(0.1 * i);
  }
  for (final strength in strengths) {
    final double ds = 0.5 - strength;
    swatch[(strength * 1000).round()] = Color.fromRGBO(
      r + ((ds < 0 ? r : (255 - r)) * ds).round(),
      g + ((ds < 0 ? g : (255 - g)) * ds).round(),
      b + ((ds < 0 ? b : (255 - b)) * ds).round(),
      1,
    );
  }
  return MaterialColor(color.value, swatch);
}
```